# Подскажите почему не переходит на некст state

Tags: python, aiogram

Нужно чтоб после того как юзер отправляет все картинки боту перекидывало на некст state (Registration.Q10)

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=['photo'], state=Registration.Q9)
async def tower1(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    photos = message.photo
    await photos[-1].download(destination_file=f'./img/{message.from_user.id}/{photos[-1].file_id}.jpg')
    file_ids = photos[-1].file_id
    await state.update_data(file_ids=file_ids)
    await Registration.next()


@dp.message_handler(state=Registration.Q10)
async def tower2(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    await message.answer('It is next state')
    data = await state.get_data()
    #db.save_questions(data, message.from_user.id)
    await state.finish()
    await message.answer('Анкета на рассмотрении', reply_markup=types.ReplyKeyboardRemove())
    for i in config.Admins:
        await bot.send_message(i, 'Появилась новая анкета! ')
```